# Magento 2 Product Search REST API Collection Filtering

Tags: magento-2.1

I am using product search REST API for listing the products based on the category. Here is my search criteria `V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id& searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=status& searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=1&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][field]=visibility&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][value]=4&searchCriteria[filterGroups][2][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]=10& searchCriteria[currentPage]=1`

I am getting the response but in which 'out of stock' products also coming. I need only 'in stock' products. Since it is not an attribute I can't directly filter the collection. Is there any other way to get the response as per my need?

Comment: Try searchCriteria[filter_groups] not searchCriteria[filterGroups]

Answer (score 0):

```
 /rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=4,7&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][1][filters][0][value]=2&searchCriteria[current_page]=1&searchCriteria[page_size]=26"
```

hopefully this will help your I'm just a newbie.

if you want status 
outofstockvalue=2 
instockvalue=1